# C# store and read large array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, database

I have an application (Winforms C#) to perform calculations on a raster. The calculation results are stored as objects in an array, total array length depending on project but currently around 1 million entries (but I want to make them larger, even 2 or 3 million). The goal of the application is perform queries to the data: the users (de)selects some properties, then the app is iterating over the array and summarize the values of the objects for each array entry. The results are shown as a picture (each pixel is an array entry).

Currently I'm storing the data as a compressed JSON string on the disk, so I'm loading all the data in memory. Advantage of doing this is that the queries are performed very fast (max 2 seconds). But disadvantage is that it takes a lot of memory, and it will give a out of memory exception if the array will become larger (I'm already building the app to 64 bit).

Question: is there a way of storing my array on the disk, without loading the entire array in memory and performing the queries in a very fast way? I've done some tests with LiteDB, but executing the queries is not fast enough (but I haven't experience with LiteDB, so maybe I'm doing something wrong). Is a database like LiteDB a good solution? Or is loading all the data in memory the only option?

Update: each entry in my array is a List of class CellResultPart, with around 1 to 10 objects in the list. Class defintion as followes:

```
public struct CellResultPart
{
    public CellResultPart(double designElevation, double existingElevation)
    {
        DesignElevation = designElevation;
        ExistingElevation = existingElevation;
        MaterialName = "<None>";
        Location = "<None>";
        EnvironmentalClass = "<None>";
        ElevationTop = double.NaN;
        ElevationBottom = double.NaN;
        ElevationLayerTop = double.NaN;
        ElevationLayerBottom = double.NaN;
        DepthLayerTop = double.NaN;
        DepthLayerBottom = double.NaN;
        DesignElevation = double.NaN;
        ExistingElevation = double.NaN;
    }
    public double DesignElevation;
    public double ExistingElevation;

    public double Depth
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsExcavation)
            {
                return -Math.Round(Math.Abs(DepthBottom - DepthTop),3);
            }
            else
            {
                return Math.Round(Math.Abs(DepthBottom - DepthTop),3);
            }
        }
    }
    public double ElevationTop;
    public double ElevationBottom;
    public double ElevationLayerTop;
    public double ElevationLayerBottom;
    public double DepthTop
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsExcavation)
            {
                return -Math.Round(Math.Abs(ExistingElevation - ElevationTop),3);

            }
            else
            {
                return Math.Round(Math.Abs(DesignElevation - ElevationTop),3);

            }
        }
    }
    public double DepthBottom
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsExcavation)
            {
                return -Math.Round(Math.Abs(ExistingElevation - ElevationBottom),3);

            }
            else
            {
                return Math.Round(Math.Abs(DesignElevation - ElevationBottom),3);

            }
        }
    }
    public double DepthLayerTop;
    public double DepthLayerBottom;
    public string EnvironmentalClass;
    public string Location;
    public string MaterialName;

    public bool IsExcavation
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignElevation > ExistingElevation)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what your data actually looks like first. Your post is not very descriptive.

Comment: MSSQL supports in-memory tables.

Comment: I feel the first mistake in this _1-million-record-processing_ ETL application is that you chose JSON as a payload.  The 2nd was that's its compressed so now all of it needs to be decompressed prior to using.

Comment: I would store this as uncompressed binary structures. That way you could use an MMF to provide efficient random access to the data (especially if you're using .NET 6+, then you can get hold of a [`SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedviewhandle?view=net-6.0) which has methods for reading and writing arrays of structs directly from and to the MMF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make some rough calculations. You have 10 doubles and 3 strings. Lets assume the strings are on average 20 characters. That should give you about 200 bytes per entry, or 200-600Mb overall. That should not be unfeasible to keep in memory, even on a 32 bit system.

Using json will probably not help, since it will make the data much larger. I would consider some binary format that should be closer to the theoretical required size. I have used protobuf .net with good results. That also support `SerializeWithLengthPrefix`, that should allow you to serialize each object independently from each other in a single stream, and that should avoid the need to keep everything in memory at the same time.

The other option would be to use some kind of database. Such a solution would most likely scale better as the size increase. Database performance is mostly an issue with using appropriate indices, I assume that is the reason your attempt went poorly. Creating good indices may be difficult if you have no idea what queries will be run, but I would still expect a database to perform better than a linear search.

Comment: Thanks, pointing me in binary direction was good solution for me. Implementing protobuf-net took me some time, but loading/saving file goes much faster now and reduces RAM memory significantly.